# For $f(x) = x^{3.2}\times e^{-0.35x}$, at what $x$ value does the maximum occur

Tags: calculus

For $f(x) = x^{3.2}\times \mathrm{e}^{-0.35x}$, at what $x$ value does the maximum occur

for minimum or maximum $f'(x)=0$

this implies $3.2 x^{2.2} \mathrm{e}^{-0.35x}-x^{3.2}\mathrm{e}^{-0.35x}\times 0.35=0$

I can't for further can any one help me

Comment: Factor $x^{2.2}e^{-0.35x}$.

Comment: sorry i m not understand your point...claude

Comment: This is a common factor to both pieces.

Comment: okk..i understand but can u please help me solve this question

Comment: @ram you can simply cancel the nonzero common factor out and get something like $A-Bx^c=0$.

Comment: $f'(x)=x^{2.2}e^{-0.35x}[3.2-0.35x]=0\Rightarrow x=0$ or $x=\frac{3.2}{0.35}$

Answer (score 1):

$$(x^ae^{-bx})'=ax^{a-1}e^{-bx}-bx^ae^{-bx}=(a-bx)x^{a-1}e^{-bx},$$ and the roots are obvious.

Answer (score 0):

we have by the product and power rule $$f'(x)=-\frac{1}{20} e^{-7 x/20} x^{11/5} (7 x-64)$$